# How can I find restaurants in the USA where tipping is not expected?

Tags: usa, restaurants, tipping

I am uncomfortable with tipping and would much rather eat at sit-down restaurants in the United States that pay their employees fairly without expecting customers to supplement with tips (as occurs in many other countries in the world). In other words, I want to eat at restaurants that explicitly do not allow tips.

Some restaurants have been in the news for [switching to a no-tip system](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/more-restaurants-adopting-no-tipping-policy/). Aside from scouring headlines, how can I find out which sit-down (not fast food) restaurants in a city I travel to will not accept tips?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77452/discussion-on-question-by-thunderforge-how-can-i-find-restaurants-in-the-usa-whe).

Comment: `In other words, I want to eat at restaurants that explicitly do not allow tips.`. I think you should change the title of your question and replace "expected" with "allowed".

Comment: Maybe ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if there is an app? If not, and you can code, developing one might be a good way to make money to pay for restaurants.

Comment: What happened to "when in Rome, do as the Romans do"?

Comment: I can’t write an answer because I just found this SE community and don’t have any rep, but I am planning a trip to US soon and come from a non-tipping country of enlightenment. I found this article of no-tip restaurants: https://smallbiztrends.com/2016/06/no-tipping-trend.html it isn’t a big list, but I’d try a couple of these :)

Comment: @Ming You always have enough rep to post an answer, even for new communities. Would you be willing to turn that into an answer?

Comment: Hi @Thunderforge sorry for slow reply, we moved house :) normally i'd have thought so too, but down the bottom when i tried, it said:
protected by JonathanReez♦ May 15 '18 at 6:09
Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Tipping is still the norm in any U.S. establishment where you do not seat and serve yourself—that is, everywhere except fast-food restaurants and places organized as food courts or cafeterias where you order at a counter. In buffet-style restaurants, where the server does not take your order or serve more than drinks, the standard is lower (10-15% instead of 15-20% in a full service restaurant), but a tip is still expected.

I tried the major food and review sites like Yelp, Zomato, and OpenTable, and none have a category or filter which makes it easy to find places with a no-tipping policy. Therefore, it seems you will need to rely on Reddit, local guides which do include such information, or indeed on headlines.

You will want to follow up on the headlines. Not only are non-tipping restaurants exceptionally rare, but as Zach Lipton notes, this trend was mostly limited to a few restaurants in major cities, and as user71659 notes, many of these restaurants ended the practice and returned to tipping — sometimes within weeks. An [NPR interview](https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2016/05/15/478096516/why-restaurants-are-ditching-the-switch-to-no-tipping) with restaurateur Thad Vogler provides some reasoning behind the reversals.

---

Per @Ellesedil, if you're interested in the *food* from a sit-down restaurant and not necessarily the experience of eating there, you can sometimes order *takeout* (aka *carryout* or *to-go*; *takeaway* is the British term but rare in the U.S.). You place the order in person at a counter or with the host/hostess, over the phone, or online; the restaurant will prepare the food and package it; you pay and leave with it. This is a common service of chain family restaurants and especially associated with pizza, sandwiches, Chinese or Thai food, and barbecue, but it is not limited to low-end establishments, as the [Morton's The Steakhouse to-go menu](http://www.mortons.com/menu/prime-to-go/) demonstrates. On the other hand, commenters have suggested that tipping is expected for takeout at some establishments, especially if the order is complex. I myself have never heard of such a thing, and [most people seem to be with me](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/is-it-ok-to-skimp-on-a-tip-when-you-order-takeout-2016-04-06) based on reports, but on the other hand I do not do takeout from nice restaurants or make complex orders. It's never *wrong* to tip a service worker in the U.S., unlike in some other cultures.

You can also order food for *delivery*, although then the expectation is that you will [tip the delivery person](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/2017/06/20/ubereats-grubhub-amazon-prime-now-how-much-should-you-tip-delivery/412062001/). This is the case both for establishments which deliver food themselves, as with many pizzerias, Chinese restaurants, or bakeries, and for third party delivery services such as Amazon Restaurants, GrubHub/Seamless, Uber Eats, Yelp/Eat24, or DoorDash among others. Often, the menu price goes to the restaurant, any delivery fee to the company behind the app or service, and only the tip to the driver. One can argue that the drivers have a worse working environment than a server in a restaurant, so stiffing the driver would be a grave act.

Not every restaurant offers takeout or delivery, but it doesn't hurt to ask the host/hostess.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77489/discussion-on-answer-by-choster-how-can-i-find-restaurants-in-the-usa-where-tipp).

Comment: You may also want to include information specifically about carry-out at sit-down restaurants. For example, even natives aren't clear if you're expected to tip or not, and could be a consideration for someone who wants to avoid tipping.

Comment: There's still [some expectation to tip for takeout at sit-down restaurants](https://thetakeout.com/ask-the-salty-waitress-should-i-tip-on-takeout-orders-1822422611), though less than if you're dining in. [Not everybody does tip in such situations](https://priceonomics.com/should-you-tip-on-takeout/), but I'd say there's more than "zero expectation for any tipping," particularly if it's a tipped waiter who is taking time away from tables to take a large or complex order and package it up or they've done something to go above and beyond.

Comment: @ZachLipton Perhaps if it's a restaurant that does not ordinarily do takeout. or [if you're an NFL quarterback](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/is-it-ok-to-skimp-on-a-tip-when-you-order-takeout-2016-04-06), but I've honestly never heard of this.

Comment: I agree with @ZachLipton; almost every restaurant I've ever eaten at offered takeout (in Los Angeles and the Midwest, including some high-end restaurants in LA), and I've always left a tip (but generally less than 20%, more like 5–10%, with a floor of a buck or two). It seems like nowadays there are tip jars out at every food-related establishment I visit except the grocery store, including fast food counters, so I would be really surprised if *most* Americans are comfortable stiffing the person who packs up a complicated to-go order.

Comment: Edited again, but the mere existence of a tip jar does not obligate one to fill it. It's a mechanism, oftentimes, for monetizing from loose change that most people don't want to carry around these days anyway. If I'm paying cash at the liquor store I will throw the loose change in the jar, but not if I'm paying by card.

Comment: A tip jar at the liquor store. Now I've heard everything.

Comment: Another suggestion regarding takeout / takeaway is that while placing the order one can ask the person taking the order whether a tip is expected, and if so how much. (I mention this because someone who is uncomfortable with tipping may find it easier to gather this information over the phone or whatever somewhat “impersonal” medium is being used for ordering.) Then one can either tip this agreed-upon amount when the time comes, or choose to cancel the order immediately (if not comfortable with the expected tip).

Comment: It saddens me that nearly 5 years later, not only is tipping still going strong, it's proliferating into more and more things.

Answer (score 74):

As your main reason to shy tipping is *‘being uncomfortable doing it‘*, I’ve added this answer, even though it misses the question given.

In sit-down restaurants, normally nobody sees you doing the tipping - it happens after you paid, and before you leave. Staff will only know the amount of your tip when you have long left (from experience, this is not known to many people outside the US).

The usual sequence in the US is:

1. You get the check (bill), server walks away.
2. You inspect it at your own time, nobody is watching.
3. (If you agree with it,) You put your credit card on it
4. Server picks it up, walks away to the cash register with your card, and brings it back for your signature, with the full amount charged to your credit card. *No* tip is added or mentioned at this time.* Server walks away.
5. You take your sweet time deciding on tip amount, add it, and sign. The amount could well be zero, if service was really bad (but that is rather harsh). Then you get up and leave.
6. Someone comes and cleans the table, and takes the signed check. Later in the day, someone types the new total (including the tip) in, and your credit card charge gets adjusted.

This removes the need to interact with the server about any piece of the tipping process. Maybe that information removes your discomfort.

* Some restaurants charge a mandatory 18-20% "gratuity" for parties over a certain size, most commonly six or more people

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77502/discussion-on-answer-by-aganju-how-can-i-find-restaurants-in-the-usa-where-tippi).

Answer (score 40):

Since no-tipping restaurants are very rare in the U.S., your best bet is going to be to find restaurants where you are doing much of the work for yourself - counter-service restaurants, for example.

There are many such restaurants in the U.S., although they veer toward the casual (most fast food restaurants are such).  Fried chicken and barbecue restaurants very often have counter service.  A good seafood joint in San Diego with counter service is Point Loma Seafoods, as another example.  Yelp should be able to help you find such restaurants.

Another strategy?  Just add 20% to the prices you see in the menus, and consider that to be the price of your meal.  If you'd eat there if they printed that as their price, in effect, that's what you're paying with a 20% tip (which is a slightly generous tip in the U.S.).

A final strategy?  You can completely avoid the tipping issue by renting hotel rooms that have kitchenettes or full kitchens, and preparing your own meals.  You'll save a lot of money too!

Comment: The first two paragraphs are off-topic as the OP specifically stated he wants sit-down restaurants rather than fast food and counter service.

Comment: @JBentley You can still sit down to eat in such restaurants, but if we answer the question literally as presented, the answer is pretty much "Good luck.  There are probably fewer than 20 such places in the U.S.  Have a nice trip!"  Others might read the question later, so a broadening of the question seemed appropriate given the narrowness of the pedantic answer.

Comment: Yes you can sit down in such restaurants, but a ["sit-down restaurant"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_restaurant) is actually a phrase with a particular meaning; it doesn't mean any restaurant that you can sit down at. Indeed, the correct answer is "good luck". The OP specifically requested sit-down restaurants, so such an answer is not pedantic. However, I suppose it is reasonable to provide such information as an aside to the actual answer.

Comment: @JBentley We call those restaurants "table service restaurants", so I think the terminology varies by dialect of English.

Comment: In addition to the 20% tip, in some (many?) locations, there is also a sales tax added to the bill. This can be up to ~10%.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie For what it's worth, those terms are used interchangeably in the U.S.

Comment: In my experience, 20% is a "slightly generous tip" in rural US and in smaller towns and cities, but in larger cities where the cost of living is higher, it's more like the baseline. If you are in New York, Boston, San Francisco, etc., tip 20% *on top of* the total bill with tax, and round up to the nearest dollar. Or more for especially good service or if you are a regular.

Comment: Sadly, I'm seeing more and more counter service restaurants moving towards adding a tip line to their credit card receipts. I find it as equivalent to begging, as it's asking for money prior to providing any type of service.

Comment: @Travis Touchless credit card transactions take care of that nicely, but they seem to be a rare thing in some countries (like the U.S.).

Comment: @Travis Instead, think of it as a partial "pay what you can afford" system which helps support the lowest-paid staff while keeping prices low in general. Or, if you're a regular, consider tipping based on service you normally get.

Comment: A lot of counter service restaurants still expect a tip.  My experience is that you hand them your card and then they swivel the screen to you with a "How much do you want to tip?" question that you have to answer on the spot which is orders of magnitude more uncomfortable than the tipping experience/exchange at a standard sit-down restaurant.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I don't view that as them "expecting" a tip, because tipping for counter service has never been part of US culture. It's just that the software they use allows it. I happily ignore the tip line and just tap through. Who cares... I'm *not* going to tip for counter service, ever, regardless of changes in technology. Doesn't bother me one bit. It's my money, after all.

Answer (score 35):

> I am uncomfortable with tipping and would much rather eat at sit-down restaurants in the United States that pay their employees fairly without expecting customers to supplement with tips (as occurs in many other countries in the world). In other words, I want to eat at restaurants that explicitly do not allow tips.

## You can't.

That's simply not how it works in the US. The restaurant in the news article you linked is notable because it is extremely rare (like, a tiny tiny handful across the entire US).

If you are uncomfortable with tipping in the US, then you need to choose fast food or counter-service restaurants, period.

At table-service restaurants in the US, tipping is expected. Is it the law? No, but this is an *extremely* strong norm in the US.

Let me emphasize this point, which has been much discussed in comments: **failing to tip at a table-service restaurant in the US would be viewed by Americans as extremely rude**.

And not just by the wait staff. On a date? Good luck getting a second. Trying to impress that American business client? Sorry, the other supplier is looking like a better fit.

Is it *illegal* to not tip your server? No. It's not illegal to write "F--- YOU" on your bill, either.

Comment: Sadly, it's also not illegal to write crap like this on it either: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-nation/wp/2016/08/21/this-couple-didnt-tip-their-latina-server-they-left-a-hateful-message-instead/

Comment: Leaving no tip is acceptable in cases of _extremely_ bad service. Although, I would leave a penny or a  nickel instead of no tip, just to make sure they knew it was intentional

Comment: @Kevin I know someone who accidentally left a one penny tip. Just a math fail. I advised her to never go to that restaurant again.

Comment: @stannius That's a pretty bad math fail

Comment: This is my own personal strategy, but I'm much more likely to complain to management and/or ask for a reduction of the bill rather than stiff the waiter. Sure, it can be the waiter's fault, but slow food or mistaken orders are just as often the fault of the kitchen, or because the waiter is covering too many tables (management issue).

Comment: While every answer provided the same, "you can't" this is the only one that actually addresses the American culture with it that it is considered rude not to. Just like many other countries have their customs that we have to learn/be aware of, this is one in the US.

Comment: @Kevin If service got so bad that I wouldn't leave even a small tip, I would probably complain to the manager and try to get the meal comped. I can hardly imagine a sit-down meal with service so poor that I wouldn't tip at all.

Comment: In many US states, restaurants are authorized to pay a wage of something like $2.13/hour on the expectation that tips will make up the rest.  They're required to bump that up to minimum wage if the tips fall short.  Granted, in theory tipping is supposed to be an indication of good or bad service.  But before you pay no tip or an extremely low tip, keep in mind that somebody is living off those wages.  At your job, do you make less money if you're having a bad day and not as relentlessly cheery as usual?

Answer (score 28):

**In general, you don't.**

There are *exceedingly few* restaurants in the U.S. where a tip is not *allowed*. In most parts of the country, you won't find a single one. There are some where tipping is not *expected*, but these will primarily only be counter-service restaurants (i.e. fast food,) not table-service restaurants with servers. Even the fast-food restaurants will generally *allow* tipping, even though it isn't expected. Some will even have a tip jar, though most people still don't tip in such restaurants.

Almost all table-service restaurants where your food is served to you expect you to tip the server in the U.S. Most towns will not even have a single table-service restaurant where tipping is not *expected*, let alone one where it isn't *allowed*.

If you *really* don't want to tip at a restaurant in the U.S., then you should plan on only eating fast food or food that you purchase at a grocery store and prepare yourself.

As far as the bit about payment, though, tips are usually pretty generous in the U.S. People who work at restaurants with tipping usually make *significantly* more than people who work at restaurants where tipping is not expected. Do not assume that workers are not being treated fairly because of the tipping system. Reality is closer to the opposite of that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77503/discussion-on-answer-by-reirab-how-can-i-find-restaurants-in-the-usa-where-tippi).

Comment: We tip either because we’re embarrassed not to, or because we know that restaurants can legally pay almost nothing.

Comment: @WGroleau Actually legally, the restaurant must ensure that any given employee's wage+tips is at least equal to minimum wage -- if they don't get enough in tips to make minimum wage, the employer is obligated to make up the difference. Me, I like to tip based on quality of service. Unremarkable service will net ~15-20% of the bill, if the service was amazing I'll go as high as 25%, and if it's crappy I'll go as low as 10%, or even $1 in one case on a ~$35 bill (to make the point that no, I didn't just "forget" to tip, that the service was *that* awful)

Comment: @WGroleau [$7.25](https://www.dol.gov/whd/regs/compliance/whdfs15.pdf). But these comments are really getting off-topic again... There's a chat link above if anyone wants to discuss minimum wage and tipping further. Please only put comments relevant to this answer here.

Comment: @WGroleau That's both not correct (see the link from the Department of Labor in my comment) and not relevant to this answer. Doktor's comment is correct, but all of these are irrelevant to this answer.

Answer (score 27):

Direct answer: **Limit yourself to less formal restaurants, which operate in "cafeteria style"**, where you go to a counter to order, and are given a pager to come collect your food, or a tent card to put on your table and a runner delivers it. (that's the last you'll see of the runner).  These are becoming surprisingly good, that is to say, *the food is good*.  The demographic is middle-to-upper-class, who want an upscale taste without the time and expense of waitservice. [Panera Bread](https://www.panerabread.com/en-us/home.html), [Noodles & Company](https://www.noodles.com), [Chipotle](https://www.chipotle.com), [Qdoba](https://www.qdoba.com), [Mod Pizza](https://modpizza.com), [Smashburger](http://smashburger.com), various Korean BBQ, etc.  As well as a variety of *locally-owned* one-off or mini-chains (Buckhorn, Firewood Grill).

**Not to be confused with waitstaffed, must-tip restaurants** going downscale by offering plain cheap food but retaining waitservice formalities (and thus the obligation to tip): Denny's, Steak & Shake, Cracker Barrel, your local greasy spoon diner, etc.  These places are for people who want to be pampered on a budget, but want plain food that appeals to their palate. In these places you will be seated, a waiter will give you a menu and listen to you give your order verbally, and that means *you need to tip*!

You can also consider **plain old fast-food**, like McDonalds, Taco Bell, Wendy's, Burger King, KFC, Arby's, Subway, Sonic, Hardees/Carls Jr, Tim Hortons, Whataburger, Del Taco, White Castle, most pizza places, etc. Their hallmarks are lab-engineered food design, industrial food sourcing and distribution, lousy ambience, salt-of-the-earth clientele, cheap pop music (Muzak), frazzled minimum-wage staff, etc.  To get the genuine American experience, make sure to be one of the 70% of customers who orders through the drive-through.

I *thought* the upscale-cafeteria type, such as Panera Bread, was referred to as "fast casual". But Google thinks otherwise, a search for "fast casual" will turn up 95% "plain old fast food", so that's useless.

If you genuinely have a medical need that *requires* you get waitservice, focus on fast-casual restaurants and request the staff help you. There is a disability-support law called ADA which obliges them to do what is easy.

Other than that, if you're a waitservice snob who insists on the formalities *but can't tip*,  that is incompatible with being on this continent.  That thing doesn't exist because the culture here is so strong, and you can't flip that culture, it's certainly been tried.  I am not here to troubleshoot your issue with tipping but to say it may be troubleshoot*able*, feel free to ask a separate question.

Comment: The ADA regulations were revised a few years back to state that only dogs (and some special rules for miniature horses) can be service animals (under the ADA; different rules may apply for fair housing law, air travel, and other legal contexts). You can't have a service alligator.

Comment: @ZachLipton bah, just as well, the bear was terrible at detecting seizures..

Comment: Useful. Would be even better with a usable google search term, but +1 for the attempt with that.

Comment: I searched the answers for “Chipotle”, and as this is the only one that mentions the example explicitly, +1 from me. :-)

Answer (score 9):

> would much rather eat at sit-down restaurants in the United States that pay their employees fairly without expecting customers to supplement with tips

This might be a bit counter-intuitive but many restaurants in the States also have something called: **service included**.

When you get the bill the *tip* is effectively automatically added. Meaning that you don't need to tip on top of that, but the service fee is already included in your check.

It seems some even market their products this way; this [trip advisor question](https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/ShowTopic-g60763-i5-k3122524-Service_included-New_York_City_New_York.html) mentions:

> they list the tasting menu at $275 service included

You might also see the wording:

> Gratuity included

This way you don't need to tip, you just need to pay your bill.

Comment: I have to admit I've never seen this. Restaurants that automatically add a service charge to the bill (commonly for tables of 4 or 6 or more, less commonly for everybody), yes, but the prices are still advertised without that service charge, and there's a small "20% service charge will be added to your bill" somewhere on the menu.

Comment: That pisses me off from a linguistic point of view.  If it's an explicit charge, it is NOT a gratuity.  And it also is independent of service quality.

Comment: @WGroleau From a practical standpoint it seems to be pretty crap too. A food blogger wrote about it in the LA Weekly saying: `It has to do with the increasingly prevalent practice of including a service charge in the final bill. The charge itself is not an issue. The problem is this: The vast majority of the time, restaurants do not verbally disclose that the tip is already included in your final bill, leaving customers at high risk of double-tipping.` http://www.laweekly.com/restaurants/why-service-included-can-sometimes-feel-like-a-scam-7552521

Comment: I wouldn't say many restaurants do this (excluding those that include an automatic service charge only for larger parties, which is much more common). A fairly small number of places do, and many of those are on the high end, with expensive dinners in a handful of major cities, often with tasting menus priced in the hundreds. There are some such restaurants, and you can seek them out, but if you want to eat at sit-down restaurants with table service, it's not particularly practical to eat only at restaurants where the service is included.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer so far to actually attempt to help the OP find the restaurants they're after. They may be rare, but these keywords will help them search.

Comment: It's not safe to assume that a restaurant which includes a service charge passes that on to the servers. I once worked in a restaurant that applied a 20% "gratuity" to all bills, and paid the waitstaff minimum wage. Yes, really.

Comment: @WGroleau interestingly enough, it is also legally not a tip.  In other words, the restaurant owner is under no legal requirement to actually give that required service charge to the server.

Answer (score 6):

It is common in some high end restaurants to implement a service charge instead of a tip. One such example is Renee Erickson's restaurants in Seattle. [Here](http://openforbusiness.opentable.com/tips/renee-erickson-on-wages-tipping-and-the-true-cost-of-food/) is an article where she discusses this. Applying a service charge is illegal in some places for parties smaller than 6. In fact, [here](http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/restaurants-secretly-add-tips-bills-lawsuit-article-1.1385156) is an article about a lawsuit over such a practice.

I suggest looking for restaurants with a service charge on Google.

Comment: And be attentive when you get the bill (after drinking all those cocktails and good wine)... There's usually still a space for an additional gratuity on the credit card receipt, don't go and add another 20% when they already included it :-)